# Curious short pattern in least common multiple of binomial coefficients

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, decimal-expansion, pattern-recognition

$$f(n) = \text{lcm}\Bigg(\binom n 1, \binom n 2, \dots,\binom n n\Bigg)$$

If we list $f(n) =\; $[$\text{A002944}$](https://oeis.org/A002944)$(n)$ it  starts of kind of boring, but at $n = 14$ we see a curious pattern in base $10$, only for four numbers (I added leading zeros for clarity):

\begin{array}{rcr}
f(14) &=& 024024\\
f(15) &=& 045045\\
f(16) &=& 720720\\
f(17) &=& 680680
\end{array}

Is this just dumb luck and I'm seeing a pattern in noise? Or is there an explanation why this 'echo' pattern occurs?

Comment: $1001=7 \times 11 \times 13$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Ah of course, I checked whether $1001$  was prime, it wasn't, and I stupidly gave up looking there. I don't know why. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern of $xy0xy$ (which occurs often in pascals triangle) comes from the fact that $1001$ is the product of a sequence of small primes that don't cancel out for small values.

$1001=7 \times 11 \times 13$